# JavaScript while vs for performance

Tags: javascript

Is it better to write:

```
var i = 0;
for (;i<MAX;++i) {
    do_whatever(i);
}
```

or

```
var i = 0;
while (i < MAX) {
    do_whatever(i++);
}
```

In the second case, the `i++` forces the use of an intermediate variable to store `i` before incrementing whereas `++i` directly increments. In my opinion, the former is faster as we just increment directly after using the variable. But the second appears to be sometimes faster. What is it better to write then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [While Loops vs. For Loops in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39969145/while-loops-vs-for-loops-in-javascript)

Comment: This is a micro optimisation at best and a premature one at that.

Comment: Also, if post- vs pre- increment is REALLY the biggest bottleneck in your application, then you can re-write the latter to `var i = -1;` and use `do_whatever(++i)`.

Comment: If iterating determined number of times, go with the canonical `for (var i = 0; i < MAX; i++)` loop for readibility and maintainability's sake. If you think a performance gain is likely, you can easily benchmark it in the context of your project (and I think you'll find no observable difference, but I might be wrong). Just my opinion.

Comment: Also: `i++` and `++i` are perfectly interchangeable here. That's the operation performed _after_ every iteration of the loop, and the subsequent iteration will get the new value of `i`.

Answer (score 2):

> the i++ forces the use of an intermediate variable to store i

No. `i++` barely equals to `i; i += 1`

> In my opinion, the former is faster

... opinions ... Have you *actually checked [which one is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)*

Comment: And I suspect both of those will be made equivalent by the interpreter optimisation.

Comment: And yet, once again, "which one is faster" was invoked. I wonder how many times you will need to mention that link :P